# How to know when a XAML element is finished loading

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a custom control I'm developing that has a collection of items. When adding an item to the collection you're meant to do:

```
myCustomControl.BeginAddItems();
  myCustomControl.Items.Add("a");
  myCustomControl.Items.Add("b");
  myCustomControl.Items.Add("c");
myCustomControl.EndAddItems();
```

If defining in XAML it would be:

```
<MyControl>
  <Items>
    <Item Name="a" />
    <Item Name="b" />
    <Item Name="c" />
  </Items>
</MyControl>
```

How can I have `EndAddItems` (and ideally BeginAddItems) called when loading from XAML? Is there any way that `MyControl` can be notified by XAML that it has finished loading?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *Loaded* event